# ASP.NET Web API - Return Object - Property Missing

Tags: asp.net, api, class, object, json.net

I'm using ASP.NET Web API to return a custom class object. The class has several properties, one of which takes an optional parameter. All the properties except the one with the optional parameter are available in the resulting JSON response. If I remove the optional parameter the other property is then available as well. Any way to return the other property with the optional parameter in place? Thanks!

Here is the specific property I'm having trouble with:

```
Public Class customer

...

Public ReadOnly Property photoSrc(Optional shape As String = Nothing) As String
        Get
            Dim srcString = "/Images/User.png"
                If shape = "square" Then
                    srcString = "/Images/UserSquare.png"
                End If
            Return srcString
        End Get
    End Property

...

End Class
```

And here is the api controller function I'm using to return json:

```
Public Function GetCustomer(id As Integer) As Object
    Dim customer As customer = New customer(id)
    Return customer
End Function
```

Comment: It it really hard to know precisely what problems you are experiencing without giving us a way to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property with a parameter is called an *indexed property*, or *indexer*.  By design, Json.Net (which is used by Web API for JSON serialization) does not serialize indexed properties, even if the index parameter is optional.  (You can see this for yourself in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L213) for the `GetSerializableMembers` method of the `DefaultContractResolver` class.)

The simplest workaround is to add a separate non-indexed property to your class which calls the indexer with the parameter value you want it to have when serialized.  You can make the property private if you want; if you do, you just need to mark it with a `<JsonProperty>` attribute to allow the serializer to "see" it.  You can also use this attribute to give the alternate property the same name in the JSON as the indexed property it is replacing.

```
Public Class Customer

    ... 

    <JsonProperty("photoSrc")>
    Private ReadOnly Property defaultPhotoSrc As String
        Get
            Return photoSrc()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property photoSrc(Optional shape As String = Nothing) As String
        Get
            Dim srcString = "/Images/User.png"
            If shape = "square" Then
                srcString = "/Images/UserSquare.png"
            End If
            Return srcString
        End Get
    End Property

    ... 

End Class
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ffNs9D

Comment: Thanks! This helped a ton!